# Create dynamic query for search using Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, filter

I need to search in my `Oracle Database` using filters based on the dropdown's. So there are total 3 dropdowns and one `textbox` for searching parameters. Now what I want is.

If User Selects `APPLICATION` from the first dropdown and `Project Name` from second dropdown and `LIKE` condition from third dropdown. A dynamic query should be created and based on that it should filter the record from the database. For that What I tried is below

```
PROCEDURE FILTER_SEARCH_DATA
 (
 P_SEARCH_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2,
 P_PARAM_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2,
 P_OPERATOR IN NVARCHAR2,
 P_TEXTVAL IN NVARCHAR2,
 P_RETURN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
 )

AS
STR NVARCHAR2(400):='';
STROP NVARCHAR2(400):='';
STREX NVARCHAR2(4000):='';
BEGIN

  IF(P_OPERATOR ='LIKE') THEN
  BEGIN
   STR:=STR || '  WHERE  AM.APPLICATIONNAME ' || P_OPERATOR || '''%' || P_TEXTVAL ||'%''';
  END;
  ELSE
  BEGIN
      STR:=STR || 'WHERE AM.APPLICATIONNAME ' || P_OPERATOR  || P_TEXTVAL ;
  END;

  END IF;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STR'|| STR);
 IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'APPLICATION' THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START APPLICATION');
 STREX:='OPEN P_RETURN FOR SELECT AM.APPLICATIONNAME, AM.PROJECTNO, AM.VSS_FOLDER_LOC FROM APPLICATION_MASTER AM 
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_DETAILS AD
ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AD.APP_MST_ID'   || str ||';';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
END IF;

 END FILTER_SEARCH_DATA;
```

But it  is not working accordingly for what I want.

Let me know if you have any issues related to this.

Comment: You don't opening cursor in you code. `open p_return for string_here ;`

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz: ohh, can u tell me how to do that. As I am not champ in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
STREX:='OPEN P_RETURN FOR SELECT AM.APPLICATIONNAME, AM.PROJECTNO, AM.VSS_FOLDER_LOC FROM APPLICATION_MASTER AM 
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_DETAILS AD
ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AD.APP_MST_ID'   || str ||';';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
```

This code just outputs a string into the standard output. You need to use this:

```
PROCEDURE FILTER_SEARCH_DATA
 (P_SEARCH_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_PARAM_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_OPERATOR IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_TEXTVAL IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_RETURN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS

  STR NVARCHAR2(400):='';
  STROP NVARCHAR2(400):='';
  STREX VARCHAR2(4000):='';
  val NVARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  IF (P_OPERATOR ='LIKE') THEN
      val := '%' || P_TEXTVAL ||'%';
  ELSE
      val := P_TEXTVAL;
  END IF;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STR'|| STR);
  IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'APPLICATION' THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START APPLICATION');
     STREX:='SELECT AM.APPLICATIONNAME, AM.PROJECTNO, AM.VSS_FOLDER_LOC 
               FROM APPLICATION_MASTER AM 
                    INNER JOIN APPLICATION_DETAILS AD
                       ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AD.APP_MST_ID 
              WHERE AM.APPLICATIONNAME ' || P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
     open P_RETURN for STREX using val;
END IF;

END FILTER_SEARCH_DATA;
```

Also, I added using of parameters (`:PARAM` in the SQL code), it helps with performance and allows to avoid SQL injections.

Another one important thing: in your code you open the cursor only if `P_SEARCH_TYPE` equals to `'APPLICATION'`. You need to do something in other cases, or your procedure will return closed cursor.

**UPD**
`STREX` should be `VARCHAR2`, not `NVARCHAR2`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Mate, It worked with some minor changes at my end.. You can post the answer on my previous question too for time being if u don't mind

Comment: @VVVV That question is different, it will look like this answer has nothing in common with it.

Comment: ohh, ok..but can we get the solution for that answer too.. if u will help, I guess we can achieve that too

Comment: sure, will see this tomorrow.. ping me once u come tomorrow